# Double GPU cuda. Can i access data on GPU 1 from GPU 2 without copying to host memory?

Tags: cuda, pci, multi-gpu

I have huge sets on data on both GPUs and I actually need each thread  to be able to access the whole data. So If i want some data from GPU 2 for thread in GPU 1, I am having Problems.
I found out about GPU Direct using PCI bus, but wanted some insight first from the people who know before jumping into it.

Comment: Run the  CUDA 6.5 `simpleP2P` [sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-peer-to-peer-transfers-with-multi-gpu), and paste the full output from it into your question.  It will answer several questions.